# sim 900a mini status led glowing constantly instead of blinking

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using sim 900a module for the first time(sim900a). Initially when i powered it with the arduino 5v supply, the power led of the board glow but the network status led never glow. After searching online for answers they showed to use external power supply with 5v 2A, then i used the specified power supply. It worked actually now the status led started to glow but it does not blink for ever 1sec or 3sec instead it glows continuously. I connected the module with the tx and rx of arduino and called the inserted sim the serial monitor detected the call and gave the output, but i cannot make a call or send sms from the module to other numbers. Pls help me out.

Comment: I am facing same problem... anybody found solution? Please help.